# Why does ant compile all classes each run?

Tags: java, ant

I'm more accustomed to make, so I'm confused why ant recompiles classes when the source hasn't been changed. I've read that there is a requirement to recompile in some cases where generics are used, but I'm not sure that this will be necessary for my project.

Also, in the javac task, I've set includeDestClasses="true"

Here's some of the targets I'm using

```
<target name="init">
        <mkdir dir="${build}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${dist}"/>
    </target>
    <target name="compile" depends="init,util,semantics" description=""/>
    <target name="util" depends="" description="">
        <javac destdir="${build}" classpath="project.class.path" debug="on" srcdir="${src}/util" includeDestClasses="true" source="1.5">
            <classpath refid="project.class.path"/>
        </javac>
    </target>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try modifying the opening tag of the `javac` task to include both a `srcdir` attribute and an `includes` attribute:

`<javac destdir="${build}" classpath="project.class.path" debug="on" srcdir="${src}" includes="util/**" includeDestClasses="true" source="1.5">`

Comment: Yes, when ant looks for source files that have changed, it does not read the contents of any files -- in particular, it does not read any class's package declaration.  Instead, it infers the fully-qualified name of a class from its filename and its placement in the source directory hierarchy.  So, for example, you may have had a class util.codec.Base64 whose source code was at ${src}/util/codec/Base64.java, but your javac task was inferring its fully-qualified name as codec.Base64 because you told it that the root of the source code hierarchy was at ${src}/util instead of ${src}.

Answer (score 8):

Your src & dest directories are not equivalent, so ant is not able to effectively stat the output files to compare them.

This is an FAQ:
http://ant.apache.org/faq.html#always-recompiles

Comment: THe src and dest attributes are specifically different to maintain the package hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience the javac target will not compile all the classes, only the ones in need of it, even without the includeDestClasses attribute.  In fact I usually set up two (or more) compile targets, one that does a complete compile (forced by deleting the output directory) and one that does a quick updating compile, much like your javac line.  Are you sure that one of your dependencies isn't deleting the output directory?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, I just ran one of the sub targets and the timestamps were all updated in my dest dir.

Comment: I'm using 1.7.0, not 1.7.1. I just tried it after editing one file, and got a 
    "[javac] Compiling 1 source file to ..." 
What happens without the includeDestClasses attribute?  Your ant output should say how many files are being compiled.